# prepareForSegue not working

Tags: iphone, storyboard, segue

I am new to iOS development. I am using Storyboards & ARC in my project. I have tried to use the  prepareForSegue method for transferring from a Table View scene to another but it does not seem to work and crashes every time I try to click on a table view cell.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
  UserTweetViewController *utvc = [segue destinationViewController];
  NSIndexPath *path =[self.tblTweets indexPathForSelectedRow];
  self.dictTweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:[path row]];
  [utvc setDictCelebrity:self.dictTweet];


}
```

Comment: Which line does it crash on? What error message does it give you?

Comment: It crashes when I try to push from one scene to another. Does not give any error message..Just lands up in the main method.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the code you show above?

Comment: Well then, it's nothing to do with prepareForSegue or the code you've shown us. You might want to edit your question and add more details as there's not much to go on.